# javascript - replace text but not alter image within p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have the following HTML.

```
<p><img src="myimage.jpg" />This is my text</p>
```

And the following javascript to replace the spaces with Non-breaking spaces. This works fine except for the fact that it removes the image.

```
$("div.myDiv p").each( function() {
    $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/ /g, '\xA0'));
});
```

Any ideas how I can replace the spaces in the text and not alter the image.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check for the nodeType and replace only this value:

```
$(function() {
   $("p").contents().each(function(i, e) {
       if( e.nodeType === 3 ) {
           e.nodeValue = e.nodeValue.replace(/ /g, '\xA0')
       }
   });
});
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/42/

Comment: I've not looked into nodeType and nodeValue before but this works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No JavaScript needed for this.

```
<p><img src="myimage.jpg" />This is my text</p>
```

and in CSS

```
div.myDiv p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Depending on your document structure, it might be useful to add an extra `imgAndCaption` CSS class to your paragraphs where needed, and do:

```
p.imgAndCaption {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Very good point... sometimes you need to take a step back to see the simple answer. Thanks - I've given jAndy the tick purely because he answered the question as I was looking to do it originally, but in this case your solution is certainly the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the text in a div and modify the text in the div ie:

```
<p><img src="myimage.jpg" /><div>This is my text</div></p>
$("div.myDiv p div").each( function() {
     $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/ /g, '\xA0'));
});
```

Comment: placing a div inside a p tag is bad practice surely!

Answer (score 1):

The image tag gets destroyed, because the img-tag is not included using `text()` so i suggest you save the image first and prepend it after your replace

```
$("div.myDiv p").each( function() {
    var $img = $(this).find('img:first');
    $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/ /g, '\xA0'));
    $(this).prepend($img) ;
});
```